# Find Set of record rowno from multiple column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two sql temp table #Temp1 and #Temp2, and I want to get rowid which contain set of temp table two

E.g. In table Temp2 have 4 record i want to search in temp table #Temp1 which contain  userid departmentid  set of record

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp1(rowid INT, userid INT, departmentid int)

CREATE TABLE #Temp2(userid INT, deparetmentid int)

INSERT INTO #Temp1 (rowid,userid,departmentid ) 
    VALUES  (1,1,1),(1,2,2),(1,3,3),(1,4,4),(1,2,1),
                (2,2,1),(2,2,2),(2,3,3),(2,4,4),
                (3,3,1),(3,2,2),(3,3,3),(3,4,4)

INSERT INTO #Temp2 (userid,departmentid ) 
        VALUES (2,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4)

DROP TABLE #Temp1

DROP TABLE #Temp2
```

i want output rowid 2 because  it contain set of (2,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4)
one thing in rowid also contain same set of record it its have one more row mean 
when i search in temp1 table based on rowid 1 then i found 4 record and when i search rowid 2 then it contain 4 record so that it is same set of record which i found

Thanks

Comment: Would you still want row 2 if it had another pair, such as `(2, 1, 1)`?

Comment: I've rollbacked question to its original state. Please do not make such changes because you invalidated existing answers, if you need further assistance consider asking new question.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume the rows in `table1` are unique.  Then you can do this using `join` and `group by`:

```
select t1.rowid
from #table1 t1 left join
     #table2 t2
     on t1.userid = t2.userid and t1.departmentid = t2.departmentid
group by t1.rowid
having count(*) = (select count(*) from #table2 t2) and
       count(*) = count(t2.userid) ;
```

This assumes no duplicates in either table.

Note:  This returns rows that are identical to or a superset of the values in the second table.

Comment: but it given me rowid 1 which i did`t want i want only 2

Comment: @bhupendrasingh . . . It wasn't clear to me if you wanted supersets or not.  I adjusted query.

Comment: @GordonLinoff You can't reffer to `t2`  with `having count(*) = (select count(*) from t2)`. You will get invalid object error.

Comment: its taking long time to executing

Comment: @bhupendrasingh . . . You want indexes on `(userid, departmentid)` in both tables.

Comment: i make some change in temp1 table how update row same on every record then this query not working

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
SELECT rowid
FROM #Temp1 t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT userid, departmentid
             FROM #Temp1 tx
             WHERE tx.rowid=t1.rowid
            EXCEPT
            SELECT userid, departmentid
            FROM #Temp2)
GROUP BY rowid
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #Temp2);
```

Output:

```
2
```

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/NDCI19772)**

Comment: i make some change in temp1 table how uplate row same on every record then this query not working